# Thymeleaf can not find internationalized messages

Tags: spring, spring-boot, internationalization, thymeleaf

I tried searching on Google but could not find any solution to my problem.

The link for code is
https://github.com/optimus29/ThymeleafDemo

I get the following output on running the JUnit test `com.jk.th.mail.util.MailTemplateTest.java` :

```
----------------------------------------------
             * Mail contents *
----------------------------------------------
Recipients: def@mail.com
Subject: Complete registraion process
Message: 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>??subject.registration.complete_en_US??</title>
</head>

<body>
    <p>??grettings.user_en_US??</p>

    <p>??registration.text.line1_en_US??</p>

    <p>
        <a href="https://www.example.com/completeRegistration">??registration.link.text_en_US??</a>
    </p>

    <p>??registration.text.line2_en_US??</p>

    <div>
        <p>
            <span>??thanks_en_US??</span><br/>
            <span>??pustakalaya.team_en_US??</span><br/>
            <span>??contact.mail_en_US??</span><br/>
            <span>??contact.number_en_US??</span>
        </p>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
----------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what is not right in the way you wrote the configuration, but...
Since you are using the default paths anyway, you could just **remove** the call (in `SpringMailConfig.springTemplateEngine()`):

```
templateEngine.setMessageResolver(messageResolver());
```

Then you may also remove the beans `messageResolver` and `emailMessageSource`.

After you do this, the only unresolved message will be "grettings" (because it's misspelled).

Comment: `emailMessageSource` was causing the problem. When I removed it, it worked. Any idea, why?